# How to Set Default Python Version for Shortcut Executables in Windows

Tags: python, windows-8, version

I have an issue where all of my Python scripts run 2.7 on my Windows 8 machine by default, but any scripts executed by clicking on them or choosing "open with python.exe" instead run 2.6. How can I specify that 2.7 should be run in these cases as well? I have made sure that 2.7 comes before 2.6 in PATH. I have also set the "Use this app for all .py files" setting with the app being "python.exe", though the options do not specify a version number. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you need 2.6? If not then there is a really easy answer.

Comment: I would rather not delete it. I would imagine my company had it installed for a reason. But I may if necessary.

Comment: oh, business, yeah don't delete it then. Can you run them with python2.7? In many systems that will be a link that works correctly.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I have not seen such an option. I would like to find one that works on Windows 8.

Comment: can you run it from the command line with python2.7?

Comment: Yeah. The only problem is when I try to run it by clicking on the executable. I have to make my software usable by someone who cannot use the command line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117763/discussion-between-oscar-smith-and-luca-del-signore).